# Embed native dll or .NET assembly into COM

Tags: c#, c++, .net, com, .net-assembly

I have a .NET library and I want to wrap it by COM to invoke its functions from C++. Fortunately, this library is open source and if I add COM-visible class right inside this project - it works:

```
[Guid("38F752CC-20F1-4729-B1E3-EE0AAD145052")]
public interface IQRCodeUI
{
    string GetDecodedString(string encodedString);
}

[Guid("D4CFCDFA-6718-494D-A23F-EBC0F9550377")]
public class QRCodeUI : IQRCodeUI
{
    public string GetDecodedString(string encodedString)
    {
        return decoder.decode(encodedString);
    }
}
```

`decoder` is a class from this very library.

But what to do in case if I would have compiled assembly? I tried to create class library (COM) and add .NET library as embedded resource to it. Without results! During compile it said something like `cannot register assembly "path\name". Cannot load file or assembly "nameOfAssembly" or its dependency. Cannot find the file.` Apologise, I can't provide original text of the error, because I have MSVS which language differs from English. Is it possible to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If your task is to call .NET library from C++ via COM, why are you adding .NET library as an embedded resource into some new COM class library?

Just make the existing third-party assembly COM-visible and call it from C++, VB6, etc.

There are several docs all over the internet on how to make .NET assembly COM-visible. None of them, as I recall, contain recommendations to embed .NET assembly into COM class assembly.

Start with:
[Best Practice in Writing a COM-Visible Assembly (C#)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/612604/Best-Practice-in-Writing-a-COM-Visible-Assembly-Cs)

Comment: As I mentioned above, my question is how to use functions of compiled .NET assembly in C++ via COM?